# C++ application performance time

Tags: c++, performance

I have a general question that comes from a specific situation I've encountered.

**The general question**: what determines the running time (calculation time, execution time) of an app written in C++ on Windows, under the MinGW compiler?

**The specific situation**: I've recently bought a new computer. While running and testing the same programs I've written on the older machine, I see not only no speed-up, but also a slowdown of performance. Both run a Windows 7 operating system.

*The older workstation*: an i7-3770 Core 4-core processor, 8 GB of RAM and a hard disk drive.

*The newer setup*: a e5-2660 v3 Xeon 10-core processor, 32 GB of RAM and also a HDD.

Not experiencing a full speed up might be due to not having a SSD memory type, but that still doesn't explain why the new computer is *slower* than the old one. I ran passmark score tests, and in all categories the new computer outperforms the old. Still, my own C++ programs and a couple of third party appications all run slower on the new machine. How could it be? Are there some specific software-type limitations I should be checking?

I'd also welcome any suggestions on the performance topic, as I plan on running calculation-intensive, multithreaded applications, so performance is an important issue.

Comment: Is the program a multithreaded program?  if it is a single thread program take a look at this: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/concurrency-ddj.htm

Comment: 4 @ 3.9 GHz vs. 10 @ 2.2 GHz, especially if you are not using *all* of those 10 cores... simple math.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I've tested on both single and multi-threaded programs. As crashmstr pointed out, a single threaded should be a bit slower (although it's actually: 4 * 3.4 GHz vs 10 * 2.6 GHz). But, what worries me the most, even a (multithreaded) program running on 20 threads on the new machine is about 2-3 times slower than a program on the older 8 threads.

Comment: @Qurious A single threaded program is only as fast as oe core -- "although it's actually: 4 * 3.4 GHz vs 10 * 2.6 GHz" doesn't make any sense. It'S 1*3.4 GHz vs. 1* 2.6 GHz, no matter how many cores either CPU has. I would expect the Xeon to win hands down thogh with a program with 10 (or 20, or 200) threads.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I understand and you are correct. It is the slower execution time on a multithreaded program that worries me the most. Although the slowdown on a single-threaded program is also substantial, a little too substantial for my intuition at least; 3.4 vs 2.6 GHz is a 30% difference, a single-threaded program running 3 minutes on the older machine should run (all other things being equal) about 4 minutes on the new one. The measured results are more like 3 minutes vs 9 minutes, that is why I suspect some other cause of the slowdown.

Comment: And then there is some room for improvement by specifying the CPU type to gcc. In order to exploit the CPUs fully one should use the Intel compiler anyway (which is mostly gcc compatible and available for free in the linux version, last time I checked).

Comment: I agree with the difference being too big for single threaded programs and completely implausible for multi-threaded programs (thread count > 4). I have no real explanation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an application uses cpu, memory and disk all of these affect the execution speed of an application.

In your case, you changed from a 4-core cpu that had 4 fast cores, to a 10-core cpu that has 10, but slower cores, effectively slowing down your per-thread execution speed.

Depending on what you do, e.g. if the ratio of calculations/memory pressure is towards the calculation side, you'll see a slow down.

Comment: And are there no software-based options I might have set up incorrectly, that may slow down the computer further? As was mentioned in the comments above, even a multithreaded application experienced severe slowdown in my specific case.

Comment: That is very application dependent. A software-setting is not that possible. Imagine the following... You have a software that uses 4 threads. If the calculation/memory pressure ratio holds you'll continue to see the performance degradation. Even it you are using more than 4 threads, there may be issues you weren't aware of with 4 cores, like contention, locking etc.

Comment: There are many unknowns here that could clarify the things a bit. E.g., are you using operating system apis ? How do you allocate/read/write memory ? Is there copying ? E.g. the way cache systems work on multicore cpus is a bit counterintuitive. With 4 cores you have experience better cache locality, thus greater speed than let's say 10 cores that are thrashing the cache.

Comment: Idea... Does your computer have any power related settings? Is your processor running at full speed ?

Comment: Good question. None that I know of -- it's a new Dell workstation, no unnecessary software in it. I have no knowledge of overclocking mechanisms, etc.

Do you have any suggestions what should I check?

Comment: If it's a workstation, it's a slim chance there will be something like that. Check your BIOS. There should be a setting called v-speed or something like that

Comment: Well, I've still to resolve the problem, but I did achieve a speedup by unsetting some Dell-specific optmizer settings. I think the BIOS setting is the best clue so far.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I caught the wrong Xeon spec at first. V3 has a faster turbo frequency but the sustainable frequency is only 2.6 GHz.

Xeon info from From http://ark.intel.com/products/81706/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2660-v3-25M-Cache-2_60-GHz:

> Processor Base Frequency  **2.6 GHz**
>
> Max Turbo Frequency   3.3 GHz

I7 info from http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/Intel-Core-i7-3770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz:

> Base Frequency    **3.4 GHz**
>
> Max Turbo Frequency   3.9 GHz

While cache size and other differences may favour Xeon in instructions/clock cycle I'd think that the 30% faster I7 clock will be hard to beat. For programs with 4 threads or less that don't have much competition for CPU time, that is ;-).